# Modernizing an old doorbell chime box

Tags: doorbell

I have an old doorbell chime box that I'm looking to "modernize". Here are some pictures: https://imgur.com/a/SpWGeio

For the chime box itself, I'm looking to probably just purchase a new chime box cover (something modern-ish on Etsy or something: https://www.etsy.com/market/doorbell_chime_cover). However, I'm not sure what the silver thing is above the chime box. Is that part of the chime box, or something else entirely?

Comment: those white wires should not be touching the gong, possibly run them across the face of the unused battery compartment or if necessary find a new home for that white box. (sound from lower gong will be improved)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have there on the bottom is a "ding dong" door bell, and on the top is the partial remains of a brrrrrrring!!!! one, missing at least the hammer and gong.  These are about $20 and $10 new, respectively (2023).

If the bottom one works a pretty cover is a fine idea.

The top one tends to get sabotaged by occupants because it's so obnoxious.

The white plastic boxes in the bottom bell look like a wireless receiver purchased separately.

Comment: the white plastic boxes look like the stuff Arlo/Ring/etc. smart doorbells attach so they can draw power from the wires without triggering the bell.

Comment: Oh - I installed the plastic boxes! Sorry, I should've pointed that out. They are for a Ubiquiti doorbell. Can I just... completely uninstall the top thingy and mud over any holes?

Comment: You can remove the upper bell but make sure its wires aren't somehow in the path to the lower door bell.  Disconnect the wires from the bell and from each other, leave them hanging in the air and make sure the bottom bell works.  If it does, cut and cap the wires and you can shove them in the wall.

Comment: And I agree with @Jasen -- move your Ubiquiti wires so your ding won't be louder than your dong.  Nobody wants that.  :)